# How to send a classic report as mail body in oracle Apex 19.2

Tags: email, oracle-apex

I have a dynamic report built using PL/SQL function returning SQL, I allow the user to enter some variables and I construct the SQL statement dynamically. I also format the background color according to a column value using JavaScript dynamic action on page load. What I need to do is to add a button to send the generated report via email (in the email body not as attachment) to a specific address. I would hugely appreciate assistance on how to do this.

Answer (score 0):

If not already done, you'll want to move the logic that generates the SQL query to a stored function so it can be called from more than one place. Then you'll want to create a new PL/SQL function that returns the data as an HTML table.

This isn't as trivial as it seems at first. You'd need to send the CSS along with the HTML - and some mail clients require inline CSS. There are some tools to help you line the CSS, such as this one: https://templates.mailchimp.com/resources/inline-css/

Once that's in place, you can use it to get the HTML for the table and add it to an email body.

Regarding the dynamic SQL, this can often lead to SQL injection vulnerabilities if you're not careful. If you share that code with us (after changing the names of tables and other identifiers), we can help ensure it's safe.